# Exception in thread during testing

Tags: python

I run my tests:

```
manage.py test myapp
```

and at the end I get:

> Ran 22 tests in 7.243s
>
> OK
>
> **Exception in thread Thread-22 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown)**

or

> Ran 22 tests in 7.243s
>
> OK
>
> **Unhandled exception in thread started by < function observe at ... > ...**

or simple

> Ran 22 tests in 7.243s
>
> OK

Function *observe()* is not called during testing (it is a separate thread), but I am getting above exceptions...

What should I do in order to tests omitted this function?

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the `run()` method of the threads into `try`/`except` can help:

```
import traceback

class MyThread(Thread):
  def run(self):
    try:
      oldRun(self)
    except:
      traceback.print_exc()

  def oldRun(self):
    # insert here the code from the original run function
```